# SendGrid get email contents. C#

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I am using send grid from my MVC application but I would like to get the HTML of the email sent via the system so that I can store a record of it (as its sent) in a database for record. Does anyone know how this could be done.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the BCC ([SMTPAPI](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/apps.html#bcc) or [WebAPI](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html#-send)) functionality to copy an email to SendGrid's [Inbound Parse](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html). Then, you can grab the content, headers, etc and save to your database.

Just a heads up, this will use one credit for the send and one credit for the BCC.